# Django DetailView additional checks based on object

Tags: django, django-generic-views, detailview

Which method should be overridden to add additional checks and redirect accordingly?

i.e. I've a DetailView for my product page, and if this product is not published (and brand has more products) I want to redirect to the brand page.

I added this check to `get` method and I'm calling `get_object()` manually and then doing my checks, but in the end I'm also calling the `super().get()` which calls `get_object()` as well, this makes the SQL run twice.

The solution I've found is overriding the `get_object()` method as following..

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    if not hasattr(self, 'object') or not self.object:
        self.object = super().get_object(queryset=queryset)
    return self.object
```

This doesn't feel right though, what is the best way to do checks without triggering `get_object` twice?

My code that calls get_object twice looks like this: without the hack above.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    product = self.get_object()
    if not product.published:
        if product.brand and #more products from brand exists#
            return redirect(reverse('brand',
                                    args=(product.brand.slug,)))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('pages:home'))

    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

just for reference super().get looks like this, and I don't want to rewrite these lines.
https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/#get

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: Is it necessary that you call `super()`? Any reason you can't just add the lines to get the context and render to response?

Comment: @Joseph I could, but I don't feel like rewriting code from DetailView. My feeling is there *should* be another method between get_object and get which allows me to do some checks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is cleaner - store the response of the `super().get(...)` call, which will also populate `self.object`, then redirect if necessary, or return the response stored from the `super().get(...)` call:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    super_response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if not self.object.published:
        if self.object.brand and #more products from brand exists#
            return redirect(reverse('brand',
                                    args=(self.object.brand.slug,)))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('pages:home'))
    return super_response
```

Note that this does have the overhead of creating a valid response for an unpublished object. To avoid that, simply avoid the super call - yes, this means duplicating two lines of code from the superclass' method:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    if not self.object.published:
        if self.object.brand and #more products from brand exists#
            return redirect(reverse('brand',
                                    args=(self.object.brand.slug,)))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('pages:home'))

    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```